# How fo force subprocess to refresh stdout buffer?

Tags: subprocess, fflush

Platform: windows 8.1
IDE: vs2013
use c/c++

Process A read stdout of subprocess using pipe redirect.

but subprocess dont invoke fflush after printf, so  processs A cant read anything from pipe before subprocess run to end.

ps: I have souce code of subprecess, but its very hard to modify them.

So whether Process A can force subprocess refresh stdout buffer to read something before subprocess run to end?  (the same effective as fflush)

Comment: related: [Python C program subprocess hangs at “for line in iter”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20503671/4279)

Comment: Very helpful.  Thx.