# Reading from a stdout in real time using node.js

Tags: node.js, file, console, stdout

I have a problem, I need to read from a console output in real time. I have a file that I need to execute, tried doing something like this `test.exe > text.txt` but when I try to read while exe file is running I can't see anything until exe finishes and write all lines in the same time. I need to do this using node.js

Comment: test.exe generates output and you need to do something with that output?  or is test.exe your program.

Comment: test.exe is a program that I start and it generates output, I tried redirecting it to file but I can't read anything from file until test.exe finishes. It goes something like this

 
`execFile('test.exe > test.txt',function(err, stdout, stderr)
 {
   console.log(stdout);
  }).on('data', function (stdout){ sendResponse(); console.log(stdout.toString() + "stdout"); });`

I need to read from test.txt while this is running and send it as a response to post request from client side. I need to do something like progress bar for that test.exe program.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use [`child_process.spawn()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) to start the process and read from its `stdout`/`stderr` streams:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var proc = spawn('test.exe');
proc.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
  process.stdout.write(data);
});
proc.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
  process.stderr.write(data);
});
proc.on('close', function(code, signal) {
  console.log('test.exe closed');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`test.exe` probably buffers it's output.

- [Disable buffering on redirected stdout Pipe (Win32 API, C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385427/disable-buffering-on-redirected-stdout-pipe-win32-api-c)
- [windows console program stdout is buffered when using pipe redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9037177/windows-console-program-stdout-is-buffered-when-using-pipe-redirection)
- [Python C program subprocess hangs at "for line in iter"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503671/python-c-program-subprocess-hangs-at-for-line-in-iter)

You can try to run it with spawn, or with a [pseudo tty](https://github.com/chjj/pty.js)

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const type = spawn('type.exe');

type.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

type.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

type.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```